# How do you get Brawler and Elite Defense?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I have not seen them show up as techniques you are able to copy. I haven't even shown them listed. How do I go about getting Brawler (especialy) and elite defense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen both Brawler and Elite Defense show up as techniques on opposing players.  They'll show, but they need to gain levels, first.  I've also seen Elite Defense as a reward from League or Tournament play.  Usually not as a first place prize, though, making it more difficult to maneuver your way into getting.

If you really want these skills, play league or tournament matches until you find an opponent who has the skill.  You can then switch to Exhibition games to sort of "freeze" their techniques until you're ready to move on.

Comment: Kulukan and Deim of the Kilika Beasts both start with both of these techniques for example. More problematic than finding players with the ability is finding players with the abilities equipped and making them use them.